# sublime text make sass files open as css extension

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I'm sure this is really basic but I'm wondering how to make .scss files open automatically as .css files? At the moment when I open a .scss file it opens as plain text and I have to manually select CSS from the extensions panel but I would like this to be automatic. Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set JSX files default to Babel text highlighting in sublime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43825586/how-to-set-jsx-files-default-to-babel-text-highlighting-in-sublime)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sublime Text 2: How to get scss and Less files to have color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16998432/sublime-text-2-how-to-get-scss-and-less-files-to-have-color)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/16998463/7527037

*Open the corresponding file with .scss extension. From the menu at the top, goto View > Syntax > **[Optional: Open all with current extension as...]** > CSS*